# losing runas user context

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, schedulebatch, runas

I'm currently trying to write tests regarding knowledge articles where the user initiating/running the tests does not have a knowledge license. Of course to do this, I need to use runAs

```
User testUser = new User(stuff goes here);
testUser.UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser = true;
System.runAs (testUser) {
    //this works fine
    system.debug( [select id, KnowledgeArticleId from internal__kav where PublishStatus= 'Draft'  AND Language = 'en_US'  limit 1]);
}
```

what about using runAs to test a batch

```
global class testbatchimplements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){       
        return Database.getQueryLocator([select id, KnowledgeArticleId from internal__kav where PublishStatus= 'Draft'  AND Language = 'en_US']);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){}

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}

User testUser = new User(stuff goes here);
testUser.UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser = true;
System.runAs (testUser) {
    //this works fine
    Test.startTest();
    database.executeBatch(new testbatch());
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

ok that works as expected. What about if we have a scheduled job that kicks off the batch

```
global class testScheduled implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC){
        Database.executeBatch(new testBatch());
    }
}
User testUser = new User(stuff goes here);
testUser.UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser = true;
System.runAs (testUser) {
    // fails
    Test.startTest();
    String cron = '0 0 * * * ?';
    System.schedule('test',cron, new testScheduled());
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

After alot of head scratching and system.debugs everyone, I have discovered that although the schedule runs in the runAs context, the batch that it starts runs in the context of the user that initiated the test. Since that user does not have a knowledge license it errors. Why does the batch not run using the runAs user? Is there a better way of testing this?

Comment: Generally, one tests the scheduler class and the batch class separately; you verify that a schedulable class actually schedules - you don't need to know that it actually launches the batch class on the scheduled date (SFDC guarantees this)

Comment: that is true, but the batch should run under the context of the user who submitted the schedule. So in my case should be the runAs user, not the user running the test. I'll just accept this behaviour as a salesforce quirk.

Comment: you can use runAs(user) and invoke `Database.executeBatch(somebatchclass)` within the block

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as to why doing the `runAs` around the start/stop test works is that batches are async calls that do not run until the `Test.stopTest()` is called.  This means that the context for the running user at the time is not the testUser but instead the user running the test.